# Integrating Power BI into C# Windows form application

Tags: c#, .net, powerbi, windowsformsintegration

I am working on an application that takes in excel inputs from the user and stores it in sql server: after manipulations, the results have to be projected in Power BI. How do I integrate Power BI with my desktop app such that it reads input from the table in the sqlserver, and display the output in a dashboard.

Comment: Try with this library [LINK](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-CSharp)

Comment: Hi. I am new to c#. Could you guide me step by step. TIA